# Number of bounded minimum vertex covers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

**Minimum Vertex Cover problem**

Input: $G=(V,E)$ and Parameter $k$

Output: Decide whether there exists minimum vertex cover of size at most $k$.

Question:-
Can we bound the number of minimum vertex covers of size at most $k$ on general graphs?

C=number of minimum vertex covers of size at most $k$

Is C bounded by $f(k)$? If not can you provide example? If yes what is $f(k)$

Comment: Do you really mean the number of *minimum* vertex covers of size at most k, or do you mean the number of vertex covers of size at most k?

Comment: i.e C= number of minimum vertex covers of size at most $k$. What is the value of C in f(k).

Comment: crossposted [from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40838067/380772) after less than 3 hours without mentioning that on either site ​ ​

Answer (score 3):

The number of inclusion-minimal vertex covers of size at most $k$ is at most $2^k$: They can be enumerated by a search tree algorithm that initially has a budget of $k$, then branches as long as the graph contains an edge $\{u,v\}$ into the two cases to add either $u$ or $v$ to the vertex cover. Each branch can be solved recursively and the parameter $k$ is reduced by one in each case.

The number of minimal vertex covers of size at most $k$ obviously bounds the number of minimum vertex covers of size at most $k$ as well.

Further information can be found in

Henning Fernau:
On Parameterized Enumeration. COCOON 2002: 564-573 [dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45655-4_60](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45655-4_60)

and

Peter Damaschke:
Parameterized enumeration, transversals, and imperfect phylogeny reconstruction. Theor. Comput. Sci. 351(3): 337-350 (2006)
http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2005.10.004